# Best way to design a database for product varients

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I'm trying to redesign my database and I'd like to follow the normalization rules, but I can't figure out how I should store product variants.

My current database design:

[image: Current database design]

So let's say I'd like to display products on my website and every product is connected to a platform.

The following are the available platforms:

1. PS4
2. PS3
3. Xbox One
4. Xbox 360
5. PC

So for example I have Far Cry 5 registered as a product and its connected to PS4, but there is also a PC and Xbox One version available, PS3 and Xbox 360 doesn't have its own version so those 2 are left out.

What would be the best way (with normalization included) to store this in the database?

So you'll have situations where a product only has 1 platform or just 3 platforms, but 2, 4 and 5 platforms is also possible.

In the end, I'd like to provide users with a link to each variant of a product on the product's page, if product has more than 1 variant.

Thanks for your help, it's much appreciated.

**Edit:**

My test database with its data:

[image]

Comment: You're describing a many-to-many relationship. It's implemented with a [Junction table](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a join table of product and platform as below.

[image]

You can then execute the following select statement to obtain the platformNames for any given productID:

```
SELECT pp.productID, pp.platformID, pl.platformName FROM Product_Platform pp 
    JOIN Platform pl ON pp.platformID = pl.platformID WHERE productID = 123456;
```

Comment: Yeah ok, but now I'm wondering how I would know how many platforms a product has and the platform's name, also each variant should have its own product columns.

Comment: These are fairly trivial things to find with the right SELECT and JOIN statements. Could you explain why each variant needs a separate column? Do you have some other unique ID for, say, the PS4 Far Cry 5 that you want to search by?

Comment: So what I had in mind was the following: All Far Cry 5 versions have their own rows in Products table and somewhere it connects all of them so I can show the visitors on the Far Cry 5 PS4 page that Far Cry also has 2 more versions, visitors have then the option to click on the urls that goes to the other version's page.

Comment: Okay, so with a join table what you have instead is each row of the Product_Platform represents a combination of Far Cry 5 and a platform, so you'd have a row of Far Cry 5 and PS4, one for Far Cry 5 and Xbox One, PC, etc.

Then you can use a select statement to get all the platforms for a particular product using the WHERE clause. If you wanted to get all the platform names for Far Cry 5, you can use the following:

`SELECT productID, platformID, platformName from Product_Platform pp JOIN Platform pl ON pp.platformID = pl.platformID WHERE productID = <your product id>`

Comment: So I setup a test database and the query only returned the given product id's platform, which was `PS4` for Far Cry PS4 row in `Products` table. From this query, I still have no idea if this product also has an Xbox One and PC version.

Comment: Does your Product_Platform table have a row for Far Cry's ID and Xbox One ID, and another for Far Cry and PC? It would help if I knew what your tables actually contained so I can help with your query SQL.

Comment: Please see my edit. With this data, I executed your query for productID 3, first I got an error saying `platformID` needs to be from 1 table (so I added `pp.` before the column name). The query returned `ProductID: 3`, `PlatformID: 5` and `PlatformName: PC`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169541/discussion-between-mihai-chelaru-and-tripledeal).